# How to load ViewModels in Kotlin Desktop?

Tags: viewmodel, kotlin-multiplatform, jetbrains-compose, compose-multiplatform, kotlin-desktop

I have an multiplatform application based on JetBrains Compose for Android and Desktop. In `common` module I have screens (as a Composable functions) with ViewModels inherited from dev.icerock.moko.mvvm.viewmodel.ViewModel:

```
import dev.icerock.moko.mvvm.viewmodel.ViewModel

class MyIpViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    // Some logic
}
```

Screen:

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    val viewModel = // How to load MyScreenViewModel() here?

    Column {
        // Screen content
    }
}
```

I need to load ViewModels inside screens. In Android it is possible to add dependency `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose` and then load ViewModels using `ViewModelProvider`. But how to use ViewModels in Koltin Desktop?

Comment: use `remember { ViewModel() }` - on Desktop there're no configuration changes, so `remember` would live through app lifecycle.

Comment: @PhilDukhov In this case it's re-creating when we are getting back from another screen above.

Comment: that's true, but it should be handled by your navigation library, as view model lifecycle should be bind to screen lifecycle. Not sure if icerock has any setup for it - their main targets are mobile platforms after all